# How to have a Rabbit MQ queue operate in store and forward mode?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

I am experimenting with Rabbit MQ using the Python Pika client.  What I'd like to do is have my AMQP sender operate in store and forward mode, i.e. be able to start queuing up messages if the server or network is down, and deliver them reliably later.  How do I do that?  My amqp-sender.py code is below:

```
    import pika
    import psutil
    import time
    import datetime
    import log
    import json
    import logging
    import uuid
    from dateutil.tz import tzlocal

    logging.basicConfig()
    logger = log.setup_custom_logger('amqp_send', 'amqp_send.log')

    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='54.191.161.213'))
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.confirm_delivery()

    channel.queue_declare(queue='ems.data')

    def get_mac_address():
        return ':'.join(['{:02x}'.format((uuid.getnode() >> i) & 0xff) for i in range(0,8*6,8)][::-1])

    while True:
        now = datetime.datetime.now(tzlocal())
        timestamp = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z')
        data = {
            'timestamp':timestamp,
            'systemId':get_mac_address(),
            'cpuPct':psutil.cpu_percent(),
            'memoryUsed':psutil.virtual_memory().used
        }
        msg=json.dumps(data)
        delivered=channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='abc', body=msg, mandatory=True)
        if delivered:
            logger.info("delivered %s" % msg)
        else:
            logger.error('failed to deliver %s' % msg)
        time.sleep(1)

    connection.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `channel.confirm_delivery()` with `mandatory=True`

`confirm_delivery` will return boolean depending if message was properly processed by Rabbit.

`mandatory` flag:

> This flag tells the server how to react if a message cannot be routed
>   to a queue. Specifically, if mandatory is set and after running the
>   bindings the message was placed on zero queues then the message is
>   returned to the sender (with a basic.return). If mandatory had not
>   been set under the same circumstances the server would silently drop
>   the message.

So you will have someting like this:

```
channel.confirm_delivery()
delivered = channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='ems.data', body=msg, mandatory=True)
if not delivered:
    # store message for later reprocessing
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried to implement your suggestions, but delivered is still True, even though my rabbitmq server is powered down.